# The Past Perfect in the narrative set in the present

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Have been reading a lot of fanfics lately, so what follows is quotations from unedited stories published on AO3. These are real excerpts from the writings of the US and the UK authors:

> She looks up from watching the slow drip of the coffee pot, blinking
> like **she’d** truly been enthralled in the process.
>
> She **hadn’t** realized **she’d** been holding it hostage in clenched hands,
> but stiffly releases it so it tumbles back against her chest when she
> next gives it a tug.
>
> **She’d** had a key made, of course, but this feels more natural.
>
> She swipes to the app and lets it load. Admittedly **she’d** never used it
> before, couldn’t get over feeling...
>
> She studies her in the dim light of the living room. **She’d** never been
> adept at guessing what other people were thinking, couldn’t be
> bothered.
>
> She swallows, thinking of the contract **she’d** just read.
>
> He smiles and takes it. **She’d** messaged him earlier the address and
> number for a lockbox with all the documents.

I just can't wrap my head around the reason they use the Past Perfect in all of these cases not the Present Perfect (or maybe the Past Simple?). I'm not a native speaker and would like to know whether it is acceptable as in the examples cited above.

Comment: I find nothing unusual about the verb tenses. They sound quite normal to me.

Comment: You shouldn't expect fan fiction to be written in perfect English grammar. Some of these sound really off to me (i.e., *thinking of the contract she'd just read*), but others sound okay.

Comment: @Jason Bassford The problem is that I find nothing of this sort reading professionally edited books. What is normal about the bit Peter Shor has mentioned: _She swallows, thinking of the contract she’d just read_?